# Hidden inputs in JSP returning as null in Java Servlet - why?

Tags: java, html, jsp, post, servlets

I'm trying to send a variable from my JSP to my Servlet using the post method. However, the value is continually returning null. I've put in prints and another type of hidden input to check for other errors, but it's just that the inputs are null in the servlet. Why is this?

JSP: (this code is within a table)

```
<c:set var="counter" value="0"/>
        <tbody>
            <form id="myForm" action="feedingSchedules" method="post">
                <c:forEach var="schedule" items="${feeding_schedules}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${schedule.schedule_ID}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${schedule.feeding_time}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${schedule.recurrence}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${schedule.notes}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${schedule.food}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${schedule.animalID}" /></td>
                    <td><button id="myButton" class="btn-danger-stale" name="btn${counter}" value="val${counter}">Delete Schedule</button></td>
                    <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"/>
                    <c:out value="${counter }"/>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            <c:out value="${counter }"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hi" id="hi" value="hi"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="numSchedules" id="numSchedules" value="${counter}"/>
            </form>
        </tbody>
</table>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

        document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
          form.submit();
        });
    </script>
```

Servlet: ('test' variable is null; code crashes at 'count' declaration because parseInt can't parse a null value)

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    FeedingScheduleDAO dao = DAOUtilities.getFeedingScheduleDao();
    List<FeedingSchedule> schedules = dao.getAllSchedules();
    //Get Parameters
    System.out.println("got here");
    String test = request.getParameter("hi");
    System.out.println(test);
    int count = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numSchedules"));
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String btn = null;
        btn = request.getParameter("btn" + i);
        if(btn == ("val" + i)) {
            System.out.println("got here");
            // call delete method from DAO
            try {
                dao.deleteSchedule(schedules.get(i));
                request.getSession().setAttribute("message", "Schedule successfully deleted");
                request.getSession().setAttribute("messageClass", "alert-success");
                response.sendRedirect("feedingSchedules");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                request.getSession().setAttribute("message", "There was a problem deleting the schedule at this time");
                request.getSession().setAttribute("messageClass", "alert-danger");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("feedingScheduleHome.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugging the code by making the form method=GET. This will help you to know the values that are going to Servlet. Then you can just check the URL to see if the data is there or not. Try this if you cannot see the data in the url that means that the form submit is not working properly.